# I cannot display some information which comes from my controller, the information which I have to display between @section('content') @endsection

Tags: laravel

Route

```php
Route::get('/pages/about-us', 'CMSController@aboutUs');
```

Controller

```
     public function aboutUs()
    {
        $aboutus = ContentManagementSystem::where('url', 'about-us')->first();

        return view('cms.aboutus', compact('aboutus'));
    }
```

View page

```php
@extends('admin.front_layouts.design')

@section('title', 'About Us')

@section('çontent') 

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div>
            <h2>{{$aboutus->title}}</h2>
            <p>{{$aboutus->description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

here I cannot show  the laravel variables , but it comes when  I simply use ,

```
    <h2>{{$aboutus->title}}</h2>
    <p>{{$aboutus->description}}</p>
```

how can I display completel.

Comment: Are you sure that it is `çontent` and not `content`?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Remul  dude you rock it....what an observation..its content . but I don't know how çontent this occured..

Answer (score 0):

check your "admin.front_layouts.design" layout
is there any @yield('çontent') or @yield('content') ?

I guess you should write @section('content') in view page

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've not added a `@yield()` to your design oage.

Go to your `admin.front_layouts.design` page and add `@yield('content')`